# Check the answer and verify from database whether it is correct or not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Fetching questions from database and displaying in screen now what should be the logical part or how to implement for checking if selected answer is correct or not and how to store correct answer in database and verifying them.

Here is the code

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","QuizQuestions");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully<br><br>";

$sql = "SELECT Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4 FROM Questions";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
$i = 1;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<br>Question: " . $row["Question"] . "<br>";
echo ' A) <input type="radio" name="ans' . $i . '" value="' . 
$row["Answer1"] . '">' . $row["Answer1"] . '<br>';
echo ' B) <input type="radio" name="ans' . $i . '" value="' . 
$row["Answer2"] . '">' . $row["Answer2"] . '<br>';
echo ' C) <input type="radio" name="ans' . $i . '" value="' . 
$row["Answer3"] . '">' . $row["Answer3"] . '<br>';
echo ' D) <input type="radio" name="ans' . $i . '" value="' . 
$row["Answer4"] . '">' . $row["Answer4"] . '<br>';
$i++;
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: so what you want? questions will have only one answer only,

Comment: [compare radio buttons with checkboxes](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25441/why-should-i-use-radio-buttons-and-checkboxes)

Comment: i want only one answer

Comment: @prabhanshupincha  you have answer below.check that

Comment: if any of the below answers was useful to you, you may accept it. This is the Stackoverflow way to say thank you for the free help you received! read here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/251777.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because all of the `radio` inputs have the same name. They all will be considered as same radio group. You need to have different names for different questions. Something like -

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>Question: " . $row["Question"] . "<br>";
    echo ' A) <input type="radio" name="ans' . $i . '" value="' . $row["Answer1"] . '">' . $row["Answer1"] . '<br>';
    echo ' B) <input type="radio" name="ans' . $i . '" value="' . $row["Answer2"] . '">' . $row["Answer2"] . '<br>';
    echo ' C) <input type="radio" name="ans' . $i . '" value="' . $row["Answer3"] . '">' . $row["Answer3"] . '<br>';
    echo ' D) <input type="radio" name="ans' . $i . '" value="' . $row["Answer4"] . '">' . $row["Answer4"] . '<br>';
    $i++;
}
```

You also can use the row `id` instead of the of `$i`.

Comment: this is the correct catch.+1.better would be if you use `ans['either question id or question itself']`  like `ans[$row['id'']]`

Comment: :) . `id` would be better as question might have a long text,

Comment: @SougataBose   yes that's why i used `ans[$row['id']]`.Please add it as a note, and your answer will be perfect

Answer (score 2):

You have set same name for all radio buttons. You should group the radio buttons for each question. For that you can get the question id from the database and set the radio button name like

```
echo ' A) <input type="radio" name="ans'.$row["id"].'" 
    value="'.$row["Answer1"].'">'.$row["Answer1"].'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have different names for each input field in the radio group so that it treats each question as a different record.